# How to get vertex connected to several vertices

Tags: gremlin

In the example below, using gremlin syntax, I want to get vertex number 1, knowing attributes of vertices 3 and 4.

So verbally - who is connected by 'created' edge to vertex with attribute name=lop **AND** by 'knows' edge to vertex with attribute name=josh

I want to specify exactly the names of edges so v.out.name.filter{it.matches('lop|josh')} is not good, as it will take all out edges of 1.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine:

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.2.4
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'lop').in('created').as('x').
......1>       out('knows').has('name', 'josh').select('x')
==>v[1]
```

The syntax you used in your question looks more like TinkerPop 2, which is out of support. You should be using [TinkerPop 3](https://tinkerpop.apache.org).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [match](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#match-step) for this (TinkerPop 3.x):

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   match(
......2>     __.as('a').out('created').has('name','lop'),
......3>     __.as('a').out('knows').has('name','josh')).
......4>   select('a')
==>v[1]
```

It reads quite similarly to your English version, though it does not start with an index look up like Jason Plurad's answer. I guess it could be inverted a bit to get the same answer:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has('name','lop').
......2>   match(
......3>     __.as('a').in('created').as('b'),
......4>     __.as('b').out('knows').has('name','josh')).
......5>   select('b')
==>v[1]
```